# Confusion with derivative rule and solving with limit definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{4x + 1 }{x -2}\text{ at }x = 5.$$

When I try to find the derivative by the definition of a limit I end up with $-1$. I tried doing it with the rule and I'm sure I went wrong somewhere but I don't know where:

$$\frac{(x-2) - (4x +1)}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{-3x-3}{(x-2)^2}$$

Comment: When you write $f(x) = \dfrac{4x + 1 }{x -2}\text{ at }x = 5.$, it would help if you said "Find the derivative of $f(x) = \dfrac{4x + 1 }{x -2}\text{ at }x = 5.$" or "How can I find the derivative of $f(x) = \dfrac{4x + 1 }{x -2}\text{ at }x = 5.$?" or something like that.  The mere phrase "$f(x) = \dfrac{4x + 1 }{x -2}\text{ at }x = 5.$" doesn't tell us that this is about derivatives; only your subject line does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient rule is $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right] = \dfrac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$.

Here, $f(x) = 4x+1$ and $g(x) = x-2$. Thus, $f'(x) = 4$ and $g'(x) = 1$.

Therefore,  $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{4x+1}{x-2}\right] = \dfrac{(x-2) \cdot \color{red}{4} - (4x+1) \cdot 1}{(x-2)^2}$.

The part in red was what you were missing. I'm sure you can finish the problem from here.